# How to build this mongodb WHERE query in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to build a mongodb query in PHP

like this in SQL:

```
select * from tbl where a=3 and b=4
```

I know this WHERE statement in PHP should be:

```
array('$all' => array('a' => 3, 'b' => 4);
```

but how to build a WHERE like this:

```
select * from tbl where (a=3 or b=4) and c=5
```

Comment: Are you using an ORM or Database abstraction-layer? If so, which one?

Comment: The first one should actually be `array('a'=>4,'b'=>4)` and the second should be `array('$or'=>array(array('a'=>3),array('b'=>4)), 'c'=>5)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array("awards" => array('$in' => array("gold", "copper"))));
```

Comment: This does not do what the question asks...it doesn't even use the same data